# Android Fragment is not displayed

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm quite new to Android dev and I followed the official Android's "Get started".

The fact is, my fragment is not displayed on the main activity ( it worked well few days ago but I changed some lines, I don't remember which ones ). I think it's a very basic problem as I don't use sophisticated fragments : it's basically one fragment inside an activity.

This is my activity :

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.mysecond.MainActivity"
tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />
```

My fragment :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And the java code for this activity (I have some other activities in the app, based on the same pattern "one fragment inside one activity" and they work well...)

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container1, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        }
    }

/**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                    false);

            return rootView;
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas ?
Thank you :)

**[edit]**
so this is my new onCreate method :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(
            R.id.container1, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();

}
```

Still not working for this activity (If I add a button in activity_main.xml I'll be able to see it but the I'm not able to see the TextView in the fragment...)

No errors in logcat and yes the activity is launched (I added some Log.e in onCreate and onCreateView and I cas see them)

Comment: Post your logcat then.

Comment: The code looks good, nothing obviously wrong there. Is the activity the one being launched i.e. is the code run in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

In your `onCreate` methode you don't have to check if the `savedInstanceState` is `null` but if the the content of the `FrameLayout` you use is `null` 
Or you simply always replace the fragment with a new one and ommit any checking.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `add`, you can use `replace`. 
You can do it like below shown code:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(
                    R.id.container1, new PlaceholderFragment());
```

Answer (score 0):

For me this work. Implementa a interface FragmentActions with the init() method and use this

```
    private void showFragment(String fragmentTag){



    FragmentTransaction trasaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    FragmentActions fragment =  (FragmentActions) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(fragmentTag);


    if(fragment==null ){  



        if(lastFragmentviewed!=null)
           trasaction.hide(lastFragmentviewed);

        fragment = (FragmentActions) newInstance(fragmentTag);  

        trasaction.add(R.id.content_frame,(Fragment) fragment,fragmentTag);  

    }else{



        if(lastFragmentviewed!=null && !lastFragmentviewed.equals(fragment))
           trasaction.hide(lastFragmentviewed);

        if(getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(fragmentTag)!=null){
            fragment.init();
            trasaction.show((Fragment) fragment);
        }else
            trasaction.add(R.id.content_frame,(Fragment) fragment,fragmentTag);

     }

    lastFragmentviewed=(Fragment) fragment;

    trasaction.commit();



}
```